# 'std::map' : 'SomeClass' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

Tags: c++

I currently have a class that looks like the following .

```
#define SET_METHOD( t , n ) \
private:    t n;    \
public:     void set_##n(  t value ) {  n = value; }

    class SomeClass
    {

        private: 
                    SET_METHOD(std::map<int,SomeClass>,hf);
    };
```

However when I do something like this :

```
SomeClass sc;
hc.AddItem(1,sc);
```

I get the following error. I have also these macros for setting up getters and setters but this time I dont know what the problem is. I am getting the following error

```
Error   3   error C2923: 'std::map' : 'SomeClass' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty' 
Error   4   error C2208: 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' : no members defined using this type
```

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated

Comment: How are the types `SomeClass` and `HistoricalFields` related?

Comment: Yes just edited the code for simplicity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the `,` in the definition `std::map<int,SomeClass>` is confusing the C++ pre-processor.

Drop the macros and define your setters/getters by hand.

Alternatively create a `typedef`:

```
typedef std::map<int,SomeClass> MyMap;
```

and use:

```
IMPLEMENT_SET_GET_METHOD(MyMap,hf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a conversion from HistoricalFields type to SomeClass type? You are also trying to define your class member in terms of class itself which leads to to a chicken/egg problem (you a trying to define a member which is a collection containig the outer class itself).